# Element with transparent background and gradient border

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

We encountered a problem in `react native`. Is it possible to create a `buttons group` with a gradient border, but a transparent background??? We tried various options, but in the end nothing came of it, so I see no reason to add code.

Comment: You can use TouchableComponent for styling and user interaction buttons. https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html#touchablecomponent. Also try out LinearGradient.

Comment: Thank you, but that’s not what i need. In your version, the ability to create a gradient background, but I need a transparent background, but a gradient border.

Comment: I think this might help you https://codeburst.io/linear-gradient-for-border-color-in-react-native-5bcab3eea1c9. :)

Comment: Unfortunately no, this only works with an opaque background

Comment: Create a transparent background + gradient border png in photoshop, apply that png as ImageBackground inside TouchableOpacity. You've got your button with  transparent background and gradient border.

Answer (score 0):

React Native doesn’t support `gradient borders`. To do that, you have to use a LinearGradient component from `Expo`. If you’re not familiar with Expo, you can go ahead and read  [introduction here](https://alligator.io/react/react-native-getting-started/) .

you have to install expo first, [installation guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/)

```
expo install expo-linear-gradient
```

After that you can create a component first, which you have already did i suppose!

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {})}>
  <View style={styles.circleGradient}>
  <Text style={styles.visit}>Login</Text>
  </View>  
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Then you can simply define some style

```
circleGradient: {
backgroundColor: "transparent",
borderRadius: 5
},
visit: {
margin: 4,
paddingHorizontal: 6,
textAlign: "center",
backgroundColor: "transparent",
color: '#008f68',
fontSize: 12
}
```

Then you have to import LinearGradient from Expo:

```
 import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
```

Then you can define the positions for the gradient to `start` and `end`. You can do this by using the start and end props. The colors prop contains an array of colors that represent the gradient stops.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {})}>
    <LinearGradient start={[0, 0.5]}
                    end={[1, 0.5]}
                    colors={['#EFBB35', '#4AAE9B']}
                    style={{borderRadius: 5}}>
    <View style={styles.circleGradient}>
        <Text style={styles.visit}>Login</Text>
    </View>
    </LinearGradient>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Notice that the `borderRadius` style to the `LinearGradient` with the same value as our View. You now have a simple button with rounded border, but no apparent gradient.

That’s because your `View` and `LinearGradient` components have the same size. Let’s add a margin to your `View` component:

```
circleGradient: {
    margin: 1,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderRadius: 5
}
```

[The official document source](https://alligator.io/react/gradient-border-react-native/)

Comment: I saw this example in other sources. He is absolutely not supportive of my condition.

Comment: What about this article: https://codeburst.io/linear-gradient-for-border-color-in-react-native-5bcab3eea1c9